# Cordova - Native Calender Integeration

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

Hi I'm developing a *phonegap application for both iOS and Android*.

i need to **integerate Calendar API to access Calendar from iOS and Android**.

I have tried some plugin it doesn't reach my requirement.

i need to **Add Event, Edit/Modify Event and Delete events** in the Native calendar.

Kindly guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope it will help u.

[Github](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin)

```
var strCalender = { "summary": strEventName,"eventDesc": strCategoryName,"begin": new Date(y, m, d),"beginYear": y,"beginMonth": m,"beginDate": d,"endYear": y,"endMonth": m,"endDate": d,"end": new Date(y, m, d), "eventtype": "1", "categoury": strCategoryName, "venue": strVenue, "color": "blue", "eventtime": strTime, "eventDate": strDate, "eventdetails": strClickStrings }

calendarInNativeApp(strCalender);


function calendarInNativeApp(eventscalendar){
        var eventHours=eventscalendar.eventtime;
        eventHours=eventHours.split(":")[0];
        var eventMins=eventscalendar.eventtime;
        eventMins=eventMins.split(":")[1];
        var eventsInfo = eventscalendar;
        var startDate = new Date(eventsInfo.beginYear,eventsInfo.beginMonth,eventsInfo.beginDate,eventHours,eventMins,0,0,0); // beware: month 0 = january, 11 = december
        var endDate = new Date(eventsInfo.endYear,eventsInfo.endMonth,eventsInfo.endDate,23,59,0,0,0);
        var deleteStartDate = new Date(2015,5,10,18,30,0,0,0); // beware: month 0 = january, 11 = december
        var deleteEndDate = new Date(2015,5,10,19,30,0,0,0);
        var deleteTitle="Event4";
        var title = eventsInfo.summary;
        var eventLocation = eventsInfo.venue;
        var notes = eventsInfo.eventDesc;
        var success = function(message) {JSON.stringify(message); };
        var error = function(message) { message; };

        if(device.platform == "iOS"){
            var createCalOptions = window.plugins.calendar.getCreateCalendarOptions();
            createCalOptions.calendarName = "Calendar";
            createCalOptions.calendarColor = "#FF0000"; // an optional hex color (with the # char), default is null, so the OS picks a color
            createCalOptions.firstReminderMinutes = 120; // default is 60, pass in null for no reminder (alarm)
            createCalOptions.secondReminderMinutes = 5;
            window.plugins.calendar.createCalendar(createCalOptions,success,error);
            window.plugins.calendar.createEventInNamedCalendar(title,eventLocation,notes,startDate,endDate,"Calendar",success,error);
        }
        else if(device.platform == "Android"){
            var calOptions = window.plugins.calendar.getCalendarOptions(); // grab the defaults
            calOptions.firstReminderMinutes = 120; // default is 60, pass in null for no reminder (alarm)
            window.plugins.calendar.createEventWithOptions(title,eventLocation,notes,startDate,endDate,calOptions,success,error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can i integerate this plugin.